# How to set NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS env variable in windows appropriately?

Tags: node.js, windows, security, https, nestjs

I have node js project and I want to run it locally in my windows computer and it should work with some `https` apis.
I need to set `NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS` env variable but I don't find the appropriate path to the `pem` file (like `/etc/pki/.../ca_trust.pem` in linux).

It seems like in windows the certificates are in the windows registry.

How can I set the `NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS` appropriately?

Thanks ahead!

I tried to set it to the path inside the windows registry.

Comment: Presumably node installations on Windows already know to consult the Windows trusted certificate stores, so there no reason to use the `NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS` environment variable. You would use that variable if you wanted to include *additional* trusted certs that are not already available on the platform.

Comment: For some reason I don't see that (I also tried to print it). Maybe is it related to the node version (16.17.0)?